# Is it possible to use whitespace with argparse from command-line? ex. --name Firstname Lastname

Tags: python, list, split, whitespace, argparse

I'm writing a script to see if a specific name is in a list, and if it is, all info found about that person is output.

I'm trying to write it with **argsparse**, and it work with only firstname. I get all the info about everyone with the name I specifies. But I don't know if it's possible with a **fullname, with whitespace between first and last name.** Because when entering:

```
python.exe findit.py test_list.txt --name Firstname Lastname
```

I get this because of the whitespace:

```
PS C:\Python\Project> python.exe findit.py test_list.txt --name Firstname Lastname
usage: findit.py [-h] [-n NAME] fbfile
findit.py: error: unrecognized arguments: Lastname
```

So my question is, is this because of the **shell** or is it possible to make it work somehow?

I have tried different nargs and .split() methods but not sure if I made it completely right because it didn't work.

With nargs = '+' I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Project\findit.py", line 68, in <module>
    name_search()
  File "C:\Python\Project\findit.py", line 36, in name_search
    if search_value in line:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

Maybe nargs is not the right way either. Or maybe it is, and if it is, the question is **how do I fix the TypeError.**

*I'm still new to Python, so I would appreciate all help I can get. **Thanks!***

The list is structured like this:

```
46720000001:000000001:Firstname:Lastname:male:City, County, Country:Place of birth::Occupation:Birth date::
46720000002:000000002:Firstname:Lastname:male:City, County, Country:Place of birth::Occupation:Birth date::
```

Here is my code.

```
import argparse

fb_file = ''
# output = {}
search_value = ''

# TODO Make that first part of the input firstname and second part as lastname.
# def search(): # Not working
#     firstname, lastname = raw_input('').split()
#     firstname, lastname = [int(firstname), int(lastname)]

def name_search():
    with open(fb_file, encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            splits = line.split(':')
            if search_value in line:
                    name_search.out = splits[0].replace('46', '0', 1)
                    name_inline = splits[2] + ' ' + splits[3]
                    gender = splits[4].capitalize()
                    location = splits[5]
                    born = splits[6]
                    occupation = splits[8]
                    birth = splits[9]
                    print('========================')
                    print('The name is in the list.')
                    print('========================')
                    print('Name: ' + name_inline)
                    print('Number: ' + name_search.out)
                    print('Gender: ' + gender)
                    print('Current City: ' + location)
                    print('From: ' + born)
                    print('Occupation: ' + occuptation)
                    print('Year of Birth: ' + birth)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'To use the Facebook Leak Lookup, type: python.exe findit.py [path_to_facebook_file] [action]')
    parser.add_argument('fbfile', help = 'Path to the file you want to analyze.')
    parser.add_argument('-n', '--name', help ='Enter the name you want to search for.')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    fb_file = args.fbfile
    search_value = args.name

    if args.name:
        name_search()
```

Comment: This is a platform limitation. If you want parameters like this to be considered a single parameter it has to be quoted.

Comment: This fundamentally isn't a question about Python, it's a question about the shell. A name supplied on the command line conceptually is a single argument, so it should just be quoted so that the shell will pass it to Python (and thus to `argparse`) as a single item in `sys.argv`.

Comment: I've closed this as duplicate but if you search [so] there are numerous similar questions.

Comment: I recommend adding a debugging `print(args)`.  From that you'll see (in the '+' case) that `args.name` is a list, not a single string.  ` '.join(args.name)` joins the string elements into one string.  It can also help to `print(sys.argv)` to see what list of strings `argparse` has to  work with.  The shell is effectively doing a `split(' ')` on the input string.